# 404 to 301 - Fixing old links

Tags: 404-error, redirect

I have currently updated a site and made many improvements to it. The old site ran off 3 different systems and had wordpress (and the other systems) in the webroot. I have moved wordpress into a subdirectory (wordpress) and I also updated my blog posts to be prefixed with blog/. Pages and the front page are not prefixed with blog/.

The issue I am having is that I want to gracefully tell Google and other search engines that these posts are now prefixed with /blog/.

I used the following code in my 404 page before I realized that wordpress throws a 404 header. Obviously, this is not the correct way to implement this fix.

```
// Check if old site URL and redirect if so
if (substr($s, 0, 8) != 'reviews/') {
    if (substr($s, 0, 5) != 'blog/' && substr($s, 0, 10) != 'wordpress/' ) {
        // Force our 301 redirect so we can keep the new URI: /blog/
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: /blog/{$s}");
        exit();
    }
}
```

What I need to do is find out when wordpress knows this is a 404 and see if it matches my checks (currently what is in the snippet above) and if a match occurs force a 301 redirect to update the crawlers.

I am not sure if this information is available on init, as this is my next step to test.

I tried playing with `template_redirect` and `redirect_canonical` but they don't seem to be the correct methods to attach to.

Any help on this is appreciated. I am still trying to find a solution and will post back when I find one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to do checks based on [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) you should hook on `wp` action. `template_redirect` will suffice too, but `wp` is earlier. This is when WP handles 404 itself. 
To perform a 301 redirect use `status_header( 301 );`, `wp_safe_redirect();` immediately followed by `exit;`

You could use [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) handle these for you. It's bit tricky to set-up if you are not that technical. Good luck.